# How to delete characters in a string?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program hat removes the character 'p' in Pineapple to output the word Pineale. Here is my current code. I found similar problems to this and thought this code would work but it is not unfortunately. Any help is appreciated!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <limits>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        remove(c,s);
    }
    string remove(char c, const string & s){
    string s = "Pineapple";
    char chars[] = "p";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
     {
        s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), chars[i]), s.end());
     }

     cout << s << endl;
     return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you did not define any c or s variables.
Second, your parameter in remove function is const, that means s is unchangeable.
The code below works in my VS2013.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

string remove(char* charToRemove, string &str){
    //string s = "Pineapple";
    //char chars[] = "p";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(charToRemove); ++i)
    {
        str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), charToRemove[i]), str.end());
    }

    cout << str << endl;
    return str;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string str("Pineapple");

    char chars[] = "p";
    remove(chars, str);

    int i;
    cin >>i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply get the position of first `'p'` from `"Pineapple"` using [`string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), then use [`string::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/). No need to put `string::erase()` inside the loop.

```
string remove(char to_rem, string s) {
    size_t pos = s.find( to_rem );
    s.erase(pos, count(s.begin(), s.end(), to_rem) );
    return s;
}
```

Modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string remove(char to_rem, string s) {
    size_t pos = s.find( to_rem );
    s.erase(pos, count(s.begin(), s.end(), to_rem) );
    return s;
}

int main() {
    cout << remove('p', "Pineapple");
}
```

Output:

```
Pineale
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  struct slash_pred
    {
      char last_char;

      slash_pred()
       : last_char( '\0' ) // or whatever as long as it's not '/'
      {
      }

      bool operator()(char ch)
      {
          bool remove = (ch == '/') && (last_char == '/');
          last_char = ch;
      }
    };

    path.erase( std::remove_if( path.begin(), path.end(), 
          slash_pred() ), path.end() );
```